# Query of one large (7MB) record by primary key from MongoDB runs CPU 100% for 5 seconds

Tags: mongodb

I have a replication set of three mongod processes running on my laptop (i7, SSD, 16GB RAM). I create an empty database and add a single 7MB record to it. I then query that record out from the command line:

```
echo "db.items.find({_id:'.......'})" | mongo mydb >tmp/junk
```

The client application "mongo" (not mongod or mongos) takes 100% CPU for several seconds before spitting out the response. If I read the record out using the Java client for MongoDB, my JVM process uses 100% CPU for several seconds before giving the response.

What could be going on here? How can I troubleshoot this?

Update: The replication set seems to be irrelevant; if I connect mongo directly to the master mongod, the performance is the same.

Update: The PHP client can get the data in some fraction of a second. Wha...?

Comment: Is the id field itself 7MB, or is the entire record 7MB?

Comment: No, the ID field is just a UUID (roughly speaking), and the object has a "value" field that is about 7MB of text.

Comment: Holy cow this insert is taking forever. I piped 7mb of /dev/urandom into a file, base64-encoded it, and am inserting it into mongo.

Comment: My insert statement is still chugging along. i7, 16gb ram, ssd.

Comment: How exactly did you insert a 7mb record into mongo? How long did that take?

Comment: I think this particular one was inserted with the Java client.

Comment: Well, after half an hour of trying to insert the thing, I get `JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. Sorry, good luck.

Comment: Might see if this helps... http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it takes `mongo` several seconds to decode the document's BSON into a Javascript object in C++, and several seconds for the Java driver to decode the BSON into a Java object. You could use `mongodump` to dump that one document to a `bson` file using `mongodump`'s `--query` argument, then try:

```
time bsondump file.bson > /dev/null
```

That'll give you a basis for comparison: the time it takes a C++ program to decode the BSON document and format it as JSON. If that's lengthy, then the sheer size of the document is the main cost.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is why you have a 7MB record. That should just be a file somewhere with mongo saying "the filename for this massive thing is ..."; That 7 MB is either structured data that is being stored horrendously improperly, or an unstructured wad of data, in which case this is definitely a file system job.

That said, what I expect is happening is that it's not just matching the id, but also validating those 7MB. Does the PHP query bypass validation?

Comment: quite. From the sound of it, that's not being used, though.

Comment: Actually it's clear that's not being used, but I think we both agree it definitely should be used in this case.